# CS0103: The name 'route data' does not exist - C# Blazor App.razor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using C# and Blazor to build out a website, and have come across this weird error in `App.razor` that makes my code not build.

I have the standard `App.razor`, as seen on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/pages-routing-layouts):

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there is nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

It is giving me an error on line 3 saying:

`/src/App.razor(3,38): error CS0103: The name 'routeData' does not exist in the current context`

This same `App.razor` file has worked fine on other projects, so what is different this time that can cause this? I believe its likely something that I have done, however what would I need to have changed for this error to occur.

Comment: Can `App` see `Program`?  Try it with `<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">`.

Comment: Tried that and hasn't worked. I have tried several App.razor files and none of them seemed to have worked.

Comment: App and Program are both in the same folder so they should be able to see eachother.

Comment: The actual error isn't necessarily with `routeData`.  The Razor compiler has found something in you code that it doesn't like.  Does `MainLayout` exist,.....  I don't have an answer.

Comment: could you pls try to delete the `.vs` folder which should be in the same folder with the sln file? Because it don't look like a code issue. maybe it's just a vs issue.

Comment: Just had the same error due to missing using statement in _imports.razor:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
is required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, adding

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
```

solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Well since we dont have much context, Im not sure how helpfull my answere will be here, but usually its

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
```

and not

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
```

Honestly im certain that this wont be the issue, but thats the only thing that comes to my mind, given the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me it helped to just close all the projects opened and also close the intellij idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have accidently moved Routes.razor to root of the project, after I have moved it back to Components folder it compiled successfully.